# How to return data from the flutter provider side to the Vue.js side via InAppWebView?

Tags: flutter, vue.js, webview, handler, flutter-inappwebview

I have the flutter application with the provider, which communicate with Vue.js application via InAppWebView JavaScript Handlers.
At the flutter side I have the method of the provider that listening to notifications from the mobile bluetooth and collect the notifications to one string message, that should be send to the Vue.js app side:

```
Future<void> listenNotifications(List<BluetoothService> services) async {
    for (BluetoothService s in services) {
      if (s.uuid.toString() == _serviceUUID) {
        var characteristics = s.characteristics;
        for (BluetoothCharacteristic c in characteristics) {
          if (c.uuid.toString() == _notifyCharacteristicUUID) {
            c?.value.listen((value) {
              allData.addAll(value);
              if (allData.length == 52) {
                collectMessage = allData.join('');
                notifyListeners();
              }
            });
            await notif?.setNotifyValue(true);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

As you can see I put `notifyListeners()` to the `collectMessage` variable, because I want to get updated value of the variable at the JS handler on InAppWebView side.
At the flutter screen with InAppWebView I have the JS handler:

```
controller.addJavaScriptHandler(
    handlerName: 'sendingStatus',
    callback: (packageData) {
        var packageData = package.collectMessage;
        if (packageData.isNotEmpty) {
            return {
                packageData,
            };
         } else {
             return 'empty';
         }
});
```

Here `package` is a `final package = Provider.of<Epack>(context);`, but currently I use the consumer - `Consumer<Epack>(builder: (context, package, child) =>...` because I want every time when `collectMessage` value changed the consumer to update `package.collectMessage` at JS handler.
Finally at the Vue.js side I have:

```
if (this.flutterChannel && this.isFlutterInAppWebViewReady) {
                                  
    this.flutterChannel.callHandler('sendingStatus').then(function(result) {
    console.log('hey Flutter');
    console.log('I got from you:', result);
    this.switchStep(++currentStep);
} }
```

As the the value of the`result` variable I want to get the string message from the `collectMessage` variable at the flutter side.
But I always get the `empty` value.

So, can somebody help me how to return updated value of the collectMessage variable from the flutter provider side to the Vue.js side via InAppWebView ?

I try to solve the problem using the flutter provider and the consumer. I get the `empty` value at the start of the work of the flutter application, but after sometime work my flutter app connect to the bluetooth device and collect all the notifications to one message, I expect that `notifyListeners()` will notify the consumer that value of the `collectMessage` changed and it should be updated. The consumer at the flutter screen with InAppWebView doesn't update `package.collectMessage` value when it changed. Probably because it works only with the widgets and doesn't update the JS handler or another reason.